# I need this in my Biology class ... using MATLAB!

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to monitor the average temperature in a fabrication every hour to ensure quality control.  How can I write a script that looks at the temperature inside the plant as a function of time, and outputs the times when the temperature drops below 10 degrees Celsius and when the temperature is above 80 degrees Celsius.  My script should say when the temperature is out of the boundary and what the temperature is. I wanna Use the following data:

```
Temperature = [-15 -5  5  15  24  33  42  51  59  66  73  79  85  90  78]
```

The first measurement is made at 5am, the last measurement is made at 7pm.  I wanna display the time in a 24 hour system instead of a 12 hour system.

Comment: Put some effort first and ask a more detailed question only once you hit a wall.

Comment: Do you need to connect to a live sensor, or is this post processing of data?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you'll need to loop through the elements of the Temperature vector and find which ones are either below 10 degrees OR above 80 degrees. In a traditional programming language you would use a FOR loop to go through the elements of an array or vector, but generally in MATLAB you want to avoid FOR loops if you can and instead take advantage of MATLAB's vectorization, because it's much faster.

You'll want to look into the FIND function (type 'help find' into the console for more information). But, for example if I had a vector:

```
A = [0 1 2 1 2 1 1 0];
```

And used

```
find(A==0)
```

The output would be a vector of the indices of A where the element is equal to 0:

```
[1 8]
```

I could similarly do:

```
find(A==1 & A==0)
```

And I would get

```
[1 2 4 6 7 8]
```

This is useful because while traditionally you access the elements of a vector with an index, you can access the elements of a vector in MATLAB with another vector. For example:

```
>> A = [-10 4 -2 3];
>> ind = [2 3];
>> A(ind)

ans =

     4    -2
```

MATLAB also makes the syntax a bit easier, because you can use the following shortcut instead of explicitly using the FIND function:

```
>> A = [-10 4 -2 3];
>> A( A<-5 | A>3)

ans =

   -10     4
```

Which would be the same as using the FIND function:

```
>> A(find(A<-5 | A>3))

ans =

   -10     4
```

I hope this helps. Sorry for the long post. It takes some time to get used to MATLAB's vectorized way of writing code, but once you do get used to it, you'll find it's very useful for computation.

Answer (score 0):

You could crate a 'time' vector like this:

```
time = 5:1:19;
```

Comment: or, for more advanced Matlab users: time = 5:19;